# JavaScript new object inside function

Tags: javascript, oop

I have one problem with OOP in JavaScript. In following example, when `newObj.position.x` is increased, `newObj.x` is not increased, despite the fact that I wrote `this.x = this.position.x`. Can you tell me why is that happening?

```js
ClassOne = function( x, y )
{
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
};

ClassTwo = function( x, y, w, h )
{
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 
 this.position = new ClassOne( this.x, this.y );
 this.x = this.position.x;
 this.y = this.position.y;
}

var newObj = new ClassTwo( 10, 20, 30, 40 );

for ( var i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
{
 newObj.position.x++;
 console.log( newObj.x );
}
```

Result of the console.log is 10, 10, 10, 10, 10...

Comment: newObj.position.x++; just increases newObj.position.x...

Comment: Class Two's x is set only once, during construction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@ArunRedhu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46130162/1541563) has completely missed the point. This has nothing to do with `newObj` and `newObj.position` being separate objects, and everything to do with the fact that `x` and `y` are primitive values.

If you leave the code provided in the question the exact same except for replacing the values of `x` and `y` passed to the `ClassTwo` constructor with non-primitive values like arrays, then the properties will reflect as expected, as shown at the bottom of this answer. This proves that the reason has nothing to do with the instantiation of separate objects in heap memory, and is simply a result of the type of parameter used.

The difference between primitives and non-primitives is that primitives are pass-by-value while non-primitives are pass-by-reference. Because of this, assigning a primitive to another variable or property causes the value to be copied rather than referenced.

```js
ClassOne = function( x, y )
{
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
};

ClassTwo = function( x, y, w, h )
{
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 
 this.position = new ClassOne( this.x, this.y );
 this.x = this.position.x;
 this.y = this.position.y;
}

var newObj = new ClassTwo( [10], [20], 30, 40 );

for ( var i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
{
 newObj.position.x[0]++;
 console.log( newObj.x[0] );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you are creating an `Object` with `new` then it allocates the separate memory in the `heap`. So the statement `this.position = new ClassOne( this.x, this.y );` allocates the new memory for the `this.position` and now `this.position.x` and `this.x` both belongs to separate memory. So when you changes the instance property for `newObj.position.x` this would not get reflect to `newObj.x`

Comment: As I understood, the point is that in the line `this.position = new ClassOne( this.x, this.y );`, a new object is created. So, basically `newObj` and `newObj.position`  are 2 different objects, right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "separate memory in the heap" or the fact that there are two objects. This answer fails to even mention the terms "pass-by-value" or "primitive", so it completely misses the point. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46155463/1541563) for the correct explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want both properties to always equal, you may use getters and setters ( and i will use the class syntax because i like it):

```
class Position {
 constructor(x,y){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
 }
 toString(){
  return this.x+":"+this.y;
 }
}

class Instance {
  constructor(x,y,w,h){
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.position = new Position(x,y);
  }

  get x(){
    return this.position.x;
  }
  set x(x){
   this.position.x = x;
  }

  get y(){
    return this.position.y;
  }
  set y(y){
   this.position.y = y;
  }
}
```

So one can do:

```
var player = new Instance(0,0,0,0);
player.x++;
player.position;//0:1
```

Comment: Okay that's just creepy

Comment: Yes I can see that >_>

Answer (score 2):

Try using `class` with getter and setter member methods so that it internally references the `position`'s values:

```js
class One {
  constructor (x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }
}

class Two {
  constructor (x, y, w, h) {
    this.w = w
    this.h = h

    this.position = new One(x, y)
  }
  
  get x () {
    return this.position.x
  }
  
  set x (v) {
    return this.position.x = v
  }
  
  get y () {
    return this.position.y
  }
  
  set y (v) {
    return this.position.y = v
  }
}

let newObj = new Two(10, 20, 30, 40)

for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  newObj.position.x++
  console.log(newObj.x)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`newObj.position.x` and `newObj.x` are 2 different values.

by doing

```
newObj.position.x++
```

You are increasing the `x` field of the `position` field of `newObj`. Thus, the `x` field of `newObj` itself won't change, as the 2 fields are not linked.

One way to link them is by adding accessors.

With `function objects`, you can create those like this :

```
ClassOne = function (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

ClassTwo = function (x, y, w, h) {
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;

  this.position = new ClassOne(x, y);

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'x', {
    get: function () { return this.position.x; },
    set: function (newValue) { this.position.x = newValue; },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'y', {
    get: function () { return this.position.y; },
    set: function (newValue) { this.position.y = newValue; },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}

var newObj = new ClassTwo(10, 20, 30, 40);

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  newObj.position.x++;
  console.log(newObj.x);
}
```

**Edit: after seeing the other answers, I would like to say that I know using es6 classes is better (at least for readability), but I wanted to keep OP's functions.**

Comment: You should probably remove `this.x = x; this.y = y;` from `ClassTwo` and change `this.position = new ClassOne(this.x, this.y);` to `this.position = new ClassOne(x, y);`, since those assignments are extraneous otherwise.

Comment: Yeah right, I forgot to change that from OP's code. Thanks for pointing it out.